# How to split long string in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, split

```
var content =  fs.readFileSync(txtPath, 'utf8');
var lines = content.split('\n');
```

when excute the second line, it crash

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:793:14)
```

the content about 800k byte, it contain 4000 lines
How can i do? 
thanks

Comment: https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(txtPath),
        terminal: false
    }).on('line', function(line) {
        console.log('Line: ' + line);
    }).on('close', function(){
        console.log('finish')
    });`

this way can run， I want better way~ please

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the existing node modules, e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line

Comment: now I use the original readline module, It can fix this problem, but I want to know why I can not spilt big string, it is not very long~